# Template states in boost:state_machine

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am pretty new with boost:state_machine, so sorry if my question does not make. I am trying to do implement a state_machine which is itself a template:

```
namespace sc = boost::statechart;

template <typename T>
class CMainStateMachine : public sc::state_machine< CMainStateMachine < T >, CStateA <T> >

friend class CStateA < T >;

public:

  CMainStateMachine(): 
  sc::state_machine< CMainStateMachine < T >, CStateA < T > > ()
  {
  }


template < typename T > 
class CStateA : public sc::state_machine < CStateA < T >, CMainStateMachine < T > >
{
  public:
  CStateA( my_context ctx ) : my_base(ctx)
  {
  }
```

when a try to compile it, it gives me next error:

> expected ')' before 'ctx'

It seems the parenthesis are well balanced, so I have no idea what can be happening. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance,

At least this basic example should compile.

Comment: Are you compiling in C++11 or higher? else closing double template with `>>` is wrong and need space.

Comment: typo? `template (typename T)` -> `template <typename T>`.

Comment: There's a lot of sloppy syntax errors in the code sample. To the point where we cannot go beyond guessing.

Comment: Sorry for being a little sloppy. I have edited the sample to reflect as much as possible what I am trying to do. Compiler is C++11, and the typo was a mistake in the post. I continue getting the same error. I don't know whether it could be related with the state is inheriting from a state_machine which is itself a template and then the argument "mu_context ctx" in the constructor can not be solved by the compiler. Just an idea.

Comment: @FerGuti I do not see how the edit helped. You still have complete nonsense (like `template < typename T > : public` ?) there effectively. I suggest you make a sample on a online compiler like https://compiler-explorer.com/, https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ etc

Comment: I saw your other edit. Here's what I get when I try to make sense of it: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a76a8fa6632474b - I suggest you take that as a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, it's not possible to reproduce your problem from the posted code. I came up with this - working - snippet trying to approximate your problem:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a76a8fa6632474b)**

```
#include <boost/statechart/state_machine.hpp>
namespace sc = boost::statechart;

struct my_context {};
template <typename> class CStateA;

template <typename T> class CMainStateMachine : public sc::state_machine<CMainStateMachine<T>, CStateA<T>> {
    friend class CStateA<T>;

  public:
    CMainStateMachine() : sc::state_machine<CMainStateMachine<T>, CStateA<T>>() {}
};

template <typename T> class CStateA : public sc::state_machine<CStateA<T>, CMainStateMachine<T>> {
    using my_base = sc::state_machine<CStateA, CMainStateMachine<T>>;

  public:
    CStateA(my_context ctx) : my_base(ctx) {}
};

int main() {}
```

Which compiles fine. Obviously you have another problem.

### Simplify

Regardless of what concrete problem you had, I notice that there's a parallel "instantiation hierarchy" of machines and states by the same template argument.

This should immediately give you the idea to simplify by [combining both under a single template](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b571eccb88b7efa):

```
template <typename T> struct SM {
    struct CStateA;

    struct CMainStateMachine : sc::state_machine<CMainStateMachine, CStateA> {
        friend struct CStateA;
        CMainStateMachine() : sc::state_machine<CMainStateMachine, CStateA>() {}
    };

    struct CStateA : sc::state_machine<CStateA, CMainStateMachine> {
        using my_base = sc::state_machine<CStateA, CMainStateMachine>;
        CStateA(my_context ctx) : my_base(ctx) {}
    };
};
```

this might remove all the future complexity!

Comment: Thanks so much sehe. Just a question, in your first piece of code, why is it needed the "struct my_context{}"?

Comment: Because otherwise `my_context` was just an undeclared symbol. Of course, your code might have it somewhere (perhaps as an alias for `T`, who knows?)